# Show only the highest value in a INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server

Hi I'm just learning SQL, I was asked to find the item that was the most popular for each customer.
I have these tables:

```
    create table sales 
    (
        "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
        "order_date" DATE,
        "product_id" INTEGER
    )
    
  create table  menu 
    (
        "product_id" INTEGER,
    
        "product_name" VARCHAR(5),
        "price" INTEGER
    )
```

So I did this:

```
        SELECT sales.customer_id, menu.product_name, COUNT(menu.product_name) AS Times_purchased
    FROM menu
    INNER JOIN sales
    ON menu.product_id = sales.product_id
    GROUP BY sales.customer_id, menu.product_name
    ORDER BY customer_id, Times_purchased DESC
```

And got this result:

| customer_id | product_name | Times_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ramen | 3 |
| A | curry | 2 |
| A | sushi | 1 |
| B | sushi | 2 |
| B | curry | 2 |
| B | ramen | 2 |
| C | ramen | 3 |

And Im happy with it since I can point out the popular iteam for each customer. But Is there a way to only see the most populat items and not the rest?
I looked at other questions here but I can't make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get most popular for each customer (get Count of Menu)

Then show popular Produnct for each customer(Row_number of Window function)

```
with _listWithCount as (
        select 
                 customer_id
                ,product_name
                ,COUNT(b.product_name) over(partition by a.customer_id,b.product_id) as Times_purchased
        from sales a
        inner join menu b on a.product_id=b.product_id
)
select customer_id,product_name,Times_purchased
from (
        select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  customer_id order by Times_purchased desc) rw
        from  _listWithCount
)d
where d.rw=1
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wOAiRI9j)

Comment: sadeghi Hey,  yeah its working, thanks! But I dont understand why you made a partition with a.customer_id and b.product_id, specially the product_id from the menu...can you explain it to me ? –

Comment: First, I calculate the count for each customer and product to find out highly of part first (example c:1 p:2 , c:1 p:2 ,c1 p:3 ; result part 1 is c:1 p:2 count:2 ,c:1 p:3 count:1 ;result final is c:1 p:2 count:2 )
if i didn't Calculate  count per product and customer,i have count per customer that isn't true

Comment: I have separated the output of each section so that you may understand more precisely.
https://dbfiddle.uk/0DprGLrT
If we don't have the count of products per customer, we don't have the most to calculate.
Again, if you don't understand, let me explain more

Comment: sadeghi Yes thank u so much for your time! Im slowly getting it haha thanks again!